# How to handle the arguments flags for an .exe file?

Tags: shortcuts, credentials, parameters, arguments, flag

Suppose that I'm using a program with a login page. And lets call  it a.exe. Whenever I execute a.exe I face a login page with empty fields such as Username, Password, Application Server, Database Server and Database Name. A user with the proper credentials can fill those out and connect to the proper server with the credentials.

What I need to find out is whether is it possible to run a.exe in "a.exe -u abc -p abc -as xyz -ds abcde -dn qwerty" format? Or add these information to some .ini or .xml or .csv or some other file?

I have hope that those credentials get stored somewhere except the password. Because after a first login, all credentials come filled automatically except the password.

So what I wonder is whether I can send these parameters in some other way ( e.g. by changing the shortcut file and adding the flags or not ??

The purpose that I want to do this is to create a few different shortcut files for different profiles. Have a shortcut for test server, another for production server and another for development server all the credentials embedded inside. It is to hard to re-enter all of those credentials each time. Any short way to do this?

Comment: That depends on whether the .exe file has been written in a way that it accepts such command line arguments. What is the exe file you are trying to run? Is it one you have written yourself?

Comment: No, it is an application written in Java. It's a corporate application and what I wonder is it accepting arguments? It has not command line interface support. Nor help ün command line works with it. I need to determine it somehow.

Comment: Issues specific to corporate IT support and networks are off topic, see [What topics can I ask about here?](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Please talk to your IT department.

Comment: Well actually I raised a flag on this on the IT department even for a whole internal community. No body could answer it. I didn't give any name of company or application. What I need is to ease and speed up my work. Nothing more.

Comment: What makes you think we can answer if it is a corporate application?

Comment: As far as it does not contain any harmful purpose to nothing or nobody. Yes it makes me think in that manner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find out where credentials are stored [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) may help.

To see how program handles it's arguments, You'll need look inside. Since You wrote it is Java [this post](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/1370/what-is-a-good-java-decompiler-and-deobfuscator) may help.

Comment: Already tried it and could find nothing. I tried scripts also, it did not work. I decompiled the exe file, could not find a trace. The only thing that I have is there's an ini file containing some of these info in the same folder but I have no idea how can I populate them for different profiles.

Comment: @ybaylav, so You know data is stored in ini file in the same folder. Easy way would be to make a script, which would replace this ini with some earlyer done copy (You can do copies for each profile).

Comment: The ini file is not containing password as a parameter. What kind  of script I can use for this?

Comment: @ybaylav, whatever You have at hand or are familiar with. Almost any language can do file copying and external command execution. In this script You need to copy ini file and start Your exe. On Windows `.bat` script would be enough, on Linux/Unix - shell. But You are not restricted to these.